# How to configure Intelij to have autocomplete on webjars

Tags: maven, ide, webjars

I successfully included webjars into my spring boot project (using maven).
The webjars I loaded are bootstrap:4.0.0-beta.2 and jquery-ui:1.12.1.

I would like to have auto-complete features on javascript inside Intelij (2017.3 EAP) HTML pages. 
The Intelij configuration needs to have file/directory (expanded jar) to work:
[image: Intelij Settings screenshot]

Is there any good solution besides:
- writing the plugin for InteliJ
- using the maven task to expand the jar onto project directory?

Comment: I don't think this is support yet by IntelliJ.  Here is a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9621